# How to add a Div on a Phaser Game

Tags: javascript, html, css, phaser-framework

I have a `game.js` where all the sprites from my Phaser game is rendered. I also have a `index.html` that calls this script to render the game. I would like to add a `<div>` for a health bar over the game.js canvas but I am not able to do it, when I try, it only shows above or below the game.

Index.html:

```
<div id="game">

    <script src="/js/game.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/script2.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/script3.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/script4.js"></script>= 

    <div id="health-bar">the code of my health bar</div>    
</div>
```

game.js:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game( 3840, 2176, Phaser.CANVAS , 'game', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render:render}, false, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `Phaser.Game` is adding a new `canvas` child element to your `<div id="game">`, which you'll see if you inspect the page.

A `<canvas>` is a block-level element, like a `<div>`, so the sibling elements will display one after the other.

If you want the `div#health-bar` to display above the canvas element you'll need to position it accordingly. There's multiple ways to do this, but one option might be adding the following CSS to your page, changing the `top` and `left` values as needed:

```
div#health-bar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  color: white;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

If you do a search for CSS positioning you'll find a plethora of resources on the topic, including [this fairly good one from Learn CSS Layout](https://learnlayout.com/position.html).

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Is there a way I could get the id of the canvas generated by Phaser? So I can use this command?

    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

Comment: There might be a better way to get what you're looking for, but I might recommend something like `document.getElementById("game").getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]` as Phaser itself doesn't appear to let you set an id on the canvas that's created.

Answer (score 0):

Easy (and readable) way address Phaser's canvas in your DOM structure

```
document.querySelector("#game canvas")
```